# building executable using python,vtk and py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, vtk

Is it possible to create a binary executable with py2exe for vtk?

Could someone provide a minimum working example or at least some hints? Py2exe is not necessary. If there is a working solution on other similar programs (bbfreeze etc) I am intrested too.

Comment: A negative vote, is one thing. A negative vote without a comment is another. Even if the question is vague, ambiguous, or wrongly phrased, you could always just leave a comment...

Comment: I think someone would have downvoted you for the question. Maybe you want to rephrase the title and make it better? Something like 'building executable using python,vtk and py2exe'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses py2exe. Use packages to add any referenced libraries and options includes to add dependencies. I am not too sure about the exact semantics and I reached this stable configuration after much trial and error. Hopefully, you can use this as a template to go ahead.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import modulefinder
from iso8601 import iso8601

setup(name='exeExample',
      version='1.0',
      description='Exe example using py2Exe',
      author='Urjit Singh Bhatia',
      author_email='person@user.com',
      packages=['example', 'someLib'],
      console=['src\\a.py',
               'src\\b.py',
               'src\\c.py',
               'src\\d.py'],
      options={"py2exe":{"includes":["someLib","csv","iso8601","pymssql","uuid","decimal","urllib2","traceback","re","_mssql","os"]}}
     )
```

Keep in mind that options, includes sometimes need to be nested. That means, if pymssql here uses _mssql, it was giving me an error saying that _mssql was missing, so I had to explicitly go and add that as a dependency.

I hope someone can improve and explain.

Edits: 
1. Added imports.
2. Simply running this creates a folder called dist where you will see the exe(s) and the dependencies.